# How to choose between a window , view or a navigation based application while developing for the iphone?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, xcode

I am a complete newbie(as is already evident) and I can't just figure out when to choose what. I have been through countless googling operations but found no help on the said question, hence had to ask here. It would be great if any of you could explain or even point me to some online resource which does it. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what your app needs. I've made an app which is a series of questions in a survey. For that I used a navigation based app.

However I'm now working on a complicated app which uses a series of navigation controllers within a UITabBarController. So for that I chose to start a window based application because there was going to be a lot of custom programming involved and that was the "cleanest slate" available.

Think about what you need your app to do, and remember the different projects you can start are all basically the same and you can always change them to suit your needs, its just what they all start with included thats different.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I think I got it now. If its not asking for too much, I have another question up at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651265/sqlite3-step-keeps-returning-sqlite-misuse-on-this-query-any-pointers . Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I would always recommend to start with Window based application template.
From a window based iPhone app, you can make any kind of iPhone application.
To learn:
I would recommend [iPhone Programming: The Big Nerd Ranch Guide](http://www.bignerdranch.com/book/iphone_programming_the_big_nerd_ranch_guide)
Get the [Kindle version](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B003EINO1W) for [your Mac - Kindle for Mac](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html/ref=kcp_mac_mkt_lnd?docId=1000464931)
 
[alt text http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/3245/bnr.th.jpg](http://img408.imageshack.us/img408/3245/bnr.th.jpg)

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. I'm looking for some books too. I guess I'll give this one a look.